# Fadein not working

Tags: jquery, fadein

In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/ewwpfonL/3/) the text displays, fades away and is replaced by other text. The fading away works fine but the new text is supposed to fade in and that isn't working. I found a lot of questions like this and all of the solutions said to hide the container the text is in. Some said to use hide() and others said to use display:none. I tried both but neither make a difference. Here's my code. Any ideas on how to make the text fade out?

```
<div id="mb-holder" class="mb">
    <div class="mb-align">
        <span id="mb-test"></span>  
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var msg1 = 'Message 1';
    var msg2 = 'Message 2';

    $("#mb-test").html(msg1);  

    setInterval(swapmessages, 2000);

    function swapmessages() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#mb-test").fadeOut(2000, function() { 
                $(this).hide();               
                $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(2000); }); 

                var curmsg = $(this).html();

                if (curmsg == msg1) {
                   $(this).html(msg2);    
                } else { 
                   $(this).html(msg1); 
                }
                $(this).css("display","inline"); 
            }); 
        });
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: So your goal is just to fade between two messages every 2 seconds? Like https://jsfiddle.net/k1vswjq7/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. Firstly your use of the `load` event handler on the `div` element will never be fired. Secondly you're setting the `display` of the element which is immediately over-riding the fade animation.

You can also tidy up the logic slightly by providing `text()` with a function to toggle the message being displayed and chaining the delay with `setTimeout()` so that the delay and fade are intrinsically linked. Try this:

```js
var msg1 = 'Message 1';
var msg2 = 'Message 2';
$("#mb-test").html(msg1); 
swapmessages();

function swapmessages() {
    $("#mb-test").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(this).text(function(i, t) {
            return t.trim() == msg1 ? msg2 : msg1;
        }).fadeIn(2000);
        setTimeout(swapmessages, 2000);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mb-holder" class="mb">
    <div class="mb-align">
        <span id="mb-test"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Tim stated, you don't need that load function:

```
$(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(2000); });
```

It attaches onLoad event to the span element every time you go to swapmessages function. You can read about this function in jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Also, no need to hide a container and change a CSS display property:

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).css("display","inline");
```

I just added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/763rf0xz/1/) where you can see messages being swapped and fading is repeated.